# MognoDB what KeysExamined means?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB `.explain("executionStats")` shows **keysExamined** of something around 103,000 but I cant find out what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#mongodb-data-explain.executionStats.totalKeysExamined):

> **explain.executionStats.totalKeysExamined**
>
> Number of index entries scanned. `totalKeysExamined` corresponds to the `nscanned` field returned by `cursor.explain()` in earlier versions of MongoDB.

Answer (score 3):

1. This are good news when you have **totalKeysExamined** > **0** , this mean your query is using index. Here it is important to understand what is the size of your database , index selectivity  , frequency and use case of this query to be identified  if 103,000 is a good examination number for your search.
2. If you have **totalKeysExamined** = **0** , and **totalDocsExamined** > **0** than you may need to create some indexes.
3. The best case is when you have **totalDocsExamined** = **0** and
   **totalKeysExamined** > **0**  , this is the case when you have the so called "covered query" , this is the fastest case where you search and load only from the index in memory and do not touch the rest part of the documents from storage.